# How to display image horizontally in scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

How to display image horizontally in scroll bar? I tried but  i am getting output vertically in scroll.Please help me

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; overflow-x:scroll; padding: 5px; display:inline-block; float:left;" >   
    <div id="slider4" class="text-center">
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team1.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">B Madhuprasad</p>
            <p>Chairman,</p>
            <p>Non-Executive</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team2.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Vineet Suchanti</p>
            <p>Managing </p>
            <p>Director</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team3.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Uday Patil</p>
            <p>Director,</p>
            <p>ECM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team4.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Rakesh Choudhari</p>
            <p>Managing Director, </p>
            <p>Stock Broking</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team5.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Radha Kirthivasan</p>
            <p>Senior Vice President,</p>
            <p>EDM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team6.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Nipun Lodha</p>
            <p>Head,</p>
            <p>Investment Banking</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team07.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Nilesh Dhruv</p>
            <p>Head,</p>
            <p>Equity Dealing</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team08.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Jayraj Nair</p>
            <p>Head, </p>
            <p>Depositories</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team09.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Ankur Mestry</p>
            <p>Head, <br/>Mutual Funds &  <br/>IPO Distribution</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <img src="img/team/team10.png">
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">Cherian MJ</p>
            <p>Vice President, </p>
            <p>Keynote ESOP</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/demos/horizontal-scrolling/ ? Your question needs to have more details http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have some images in scroll bar, i am getting vertically output but i want to display all images horizontally in scroll.

Comment: Make `#slider4` at least as wide as all elements in it combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `width` to your wrapper, set the `white-space`  to `nowrap`  and finally `overflow-x`  to `scroll`. The container of the images won't grow beyond the specified width, and the images will all be displayed inside of it. Once the images are too big for the container, they will be cutoff and you get a scrollbar below the slider.

```
.wrapper{
    width: 500px; 
    overflow-x:scroll;     
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/a9zq2Ly2/

Comment: .imageHolder { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 285px; 
    height: 175px;
     } 
 .imageHolder .caption { 
    opacity: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    height:50px;
    width: 283px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: black; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-weight:bold;
     } 

 .imageHolder:hover .caption { opacity: 0.7;
  }

Comment: i need your help when cursor goes to button image will change and caption also change .can you help me how to do.

Comment: i have 5 button and when cursor goes to button all caption showing automatically but i dont want like this.i want only one caption at time

Answer (score 0):

try to refer some sources from web

http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/photo-galleries/css-horizontal-scroller.php

http://www.wickham43.net/imageswithascrollbar.php

Comment: hi Alpesh rathod that link which you given to me that very great full for me. i need your help i am not getting scroll bar horizontally .i want all images on one row

Comment: @Narendraverma do a try here , http://www.blogbulk.com/2008/11/more-pictures-in-one-row-or-side-by.html

Comment: and one more think i have 10 images in my scroll bar i want to show first 5 than scroll the bar than next 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html:

```
<div class="wrapper">   
    <div id="slider4" class="text-center">
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>7</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>8</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>9</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>11</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>12</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>13</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-img">
            <p>15</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}
#slider4{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slide-img{
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suraj_mewada/3zgmfkx0/)

Comment: Hi suraj i want vertically and horizontal scroll bar .when i am using my image inside scroll i am not getting vertically scroll.please help me

Comment: Hi Narendra, if your image size is bigger then the wrapper height then only you will get the vertical scroll.