# Is it possible to display multiple images in a chunk in R markdown with a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, r, image, scrollbar, r-markdown

I am trying to create a report in R Markdown (with an html output) that embeds multiple MRI images of the brain using a vertical scrollbar. The ultimate goal is to be able to use the scrollbar, to go through the brain images from top to bottom or vice versa. I have viewed the following post: [How to display image horizontally in scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507510/how-to-display-image-horizontally-in-scroll-bar) but am unsure how to use this code in R markdown. I'm very new to coding so am not sure how difficult my problem is.

I am using the function knitr::include_graphics to display my images when knit to HTML, and I'm wondering what I should add to vertically scroll through these images.

An example using 3 images in the report is as follows:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align="center"}
library(knitr)
knitr::include_graphics('1.jpg')
knitr::include_graphics('2.jpg')
knitr::include_graphics('3.jpg')
```
````

What should I add to this chunk in R markdown, to allow for vertical scrolling of these images? Any help is appreciated, as the link I've described previously was above my level of understanding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work but requires you to set the width and height of your box manually.

````
# Put this in your css (without the style tags), or at the top of your Rmd document 
<style>
.vscroll-plot {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

# In your Rmd document wrap your code chunk in div tags with class vscroll-plot
<div class="vscroll-plot">
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$drat);
plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$qsec);
```
</div>
````

This will give you both plots with a vertical scroll bar if the plots exceed the specified height.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a scroll bar could be a simple embedded viewer allowing to switch between images. For example, if all the images have the same XY dimensions you could use the one provided by the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) package *[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage)* (for the time being this functionality is available only in the development branch which can be obtained from [GitHub](https://github.com/aoles/EBImage)).

```
library("EBImage")

imgs <- c('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg')
display(readImage(imgs), method="browser")
```